Using NavigationStack
This creates an intermediate view with text that I must tap to get to my detail v iew.  How can I eliminate the middle man and navigate directly to my detail view?
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
let i: Int = 1
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        NavigationLink("Select \(i)", value: i)
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { selection in
                DetailView(number: i)
            }
    }
}

}
Here is Paul Hudson's example.  It also gets an intermediate view:

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is the detail view")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    DetailView()
                } label: {
                    Label("Show Detail View", systemImage: "globe")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }
    }


Use the presentation method:
.navigationDestination(isPresented: $viewModel.showMore) {
            MoreActionsView()
        }

